# How to handle a migrated question from Quant that isn't very good

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm an irregular contributor to money, but just saw this

[Why should I worry about the variance of the return?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14175/why-should-i-worry-about-the-variance-of-the-return)

It was migrated from Quant, and already has an accepted answer.  Were it to have been posed originally on Money, I would probably have at least commented that it was poorly worded, and might even have voted to close as off topic.

Now that money "owns" it, what do to?

Comment: All answers have been posted after the migration. If it's off-topic (and the fact that there are no valid tags and [untagged] is used is a point in favour of that argument), it can/should be voted to close as such.

Comment: why is there a quant site at all?  exclusive club where us normal peons can't understand/aren't allowed to use such theory?  it should be absorbed into money

Comment: I would not think of it as exclusive, but as a different focus.  Some cooking questions might be better answered on outdoors.  Does not mean that cooking.se should not exist.